# Laravel - How to get model name or instance from route for store resource

Tags: laravel, model, routes

I am trying to get the model to get to the table name for a Form request, for validation to store a new model.
I have several models that have the same structure in the tables (id, name, lang_id).
There for, to keep my code as “DRY” as possible, I want to use the same validation for all of these models to check if the new entry is unique like so:

```
public function rules( Request $request) { 
  return [
    "nameFr"  => "required|unique:" . $table .",name|min:3|max:100",
    "nameEn"  => "required|unique:" . $table . ",name|min:3|max:100",
];
```

I have tested this in my update request in the Form request validation and I do get the table name, using this:

```
$table = collect( $this->route()->parameters() )->first()->getTable();
```

Trying it for the store request in the Form request validation:

```
$table = collect( $this->route()->parameters() );
```

Only returns an empty collection.

It’s like the parameters have not yet been added to the route.

I have a way to get it but it's not as clean using:

```
$table = explode( "/", $request->url()  ); // --> returns an array

array:5 [
  0 => "http:"
  1 => ""
  2 => "domain.local"
  3 => "admin"
  4 => "mymodels"
]
```

and then:

```
$table = end ($table); // --> To get the last part of the uri which is the part I need "mymodels"
```

Should the URI change adding another segment to the URI, I could have to update the code.

Any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: I have seen a lot of Laravel projects, just hardcode it, you are solving a problem that is not there.

Comment: There are no parameters on a resource's store route. As @mrhn says, you're creating work for yourself. Just use one `FormRequest` class for each of your controllers.

Comment: Ya that's exactly what I have done first! 
I am trying to refactor my code so it's cleaner.
Thanks

Comment: @miken32 - So I can understand. Why is there no paramerters with a store route?
It's bind to model to be stored.

Comment: If you look at the route definitions with `artisan route:list` you can see. Route parameters are in the URL with braces for requests like update or show, because they refer to an existing object. For store requests, there is no object yet, so no ID to represent it.

Comment: @miken32 - Thanks! Makes sence.

Comment: I agree with DRY but this is not the case, also think about readability, one of the nice things about form requests is its almost a blueprint of what you expect to receive in the controller and combining it with validated() method on the request makes it quite powerfull

Comment: please set `dd($request)` in the first line of your validation method `public function rules( Request $request)` and then find the table name in its properties

Comment: @Hamid - I tried that before posting. But could not find a way to retrieve the model nor the table name. Any idea how?

Comment: @Hamid - The only way I could use the $request, is if I pass it a hidden input in the form with the name of the current model, and get it this way $request->model. I was looking for a way to get it only form back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

**1. using `Request::segments()`**
you can retrieve A Request URI Segment by `Request` facade

```
public function rules( Request $request) {
   dd($request->segments(),
      \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::segments(),
       $request->segment(1));
   //$table=$request->segment(1);
}
```

**2. using route parameters in web route**
you can retrive a part of url by `{variablename}`and send it as variable in controller

`Route::post('/admin/{modelname}/get',function($modelname){
    dd($modelname);
});`

Comment: Thanks Hamid. I will use your first solution.